# How to initiate a HashSet with Enumeration Values?

Tags: java, enums, hashset

I am working with a library with a method with have a HashSet with enumaration parameter, and i ain't able to call that method. I think that question is probably easiest that i think, but i have this problem from two days.
Follow the method in library:

```
public int searchCard(HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> var1, int var2, OnCardInfoListener var3) {
    if(var2 >= 0 && var3 != null) {
        u.a().a(var1, var2, var3);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Follow the enumaration CardSlotTypeEnum:

```
public enum CardSlotTypeEnum {
    ICC1,
    ICC2,
    ICC3,
    PSAM1,
    PSAM2,
    PSAM3,
    RF,
    SWIPE,
}
```

Follow my code:

```
reader = deviceEngine.getCardReader();
OnCardInfoListener info = new OnCardInfoListener() {};
HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> teste = new HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum>();

reader.searchCard(teste,60,info);
```

I'm having problems to initialize the 'teste' variable, this way was the only that don't are giving some message of error to me, but in this case the 'teste' aren't receiving nothing.

If someone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: What error are you seeing? Your `HashSet` is being appropriately instantiated, but is an empty collection because you've never added anything to it. Your logic is simply instantiating an empty `Set`. You need to instantiate, then you need to invoke `.add(CardSlotTypeEnum)` in a loop over `CardSlotTypeEnum.values()` to get some references into that `Set`

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are trying to do. `HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> teste = new HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum>();` creates set *for* CardSlotTypeEnum values. If you want to add some values to it just use code like `teste.add(CardSlotTypeEnum.PSAM1);`. If that is not what you want then please [edit] your question and add more details

Comment: @FFigueredo - This appears to be purely a Java question.  I suggest you remove the "Android" and "Android-Studio" tags.

Comment: EJK, i am working with android-studio. How i have little knowledge of this language, how can i know that it is java. I put the tag, simply because of i am work with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little strange that this library is using `HashSet` instead of `EnumSet`, but if that's what you're stuck with then so be it.

It's very easy to create an `EnumSet` that has all values in your `enum` class. You can then create a `HashSet` quite easily from that:

```
EnumSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> enums = EnumSet.allOf(CardSlotTypeEnum.class);
HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> teste = new HashSet<>(enums);
```

### Edit

If you only want to add specific enum constants to the set, you can simply do that manually:

```
HashSet<CardSlotTypeEnum> teste = new HashSet<>();
teste.add(CardSlotTypeEnum.RF);
teste.add(CardSlotTypeEnum.SWIPE);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you my friend. One last doubt, how can i pass just the last value of the enums, for example, from the variable 'teste'?

Comment: @FFigueredo I've updated my answer to address your question. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend. It was just what i needed.