# Is there a way to auto-populate a C# HashSet with the enumerations included in an enum?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an enum `MyColors` defined like this:

```
enum MyColors { Red, Green, Blue }
```

And I want to populate a HashSet with the enumerations of that enum.
The only way I know to do that is:

```
var allColors = new HashSet<MyColors> { MyColors.Red, MyColors.Green, MyColors.Blue }
```

The problem is that **every time I add a color to the enum I have to update my hashset as well.**

Is there a way to define that HashSet without manually copying the values from the enum?

**Bonus points:** The HashSet is a readonly field so it needs to be initialized when it is defined.

Note that `Enum.GetValues` and `Enum.GetNames` will not help because the HashSet is of type `MyColors` and those functions return different types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102445/how-to-initiate-a-hashset-with-enumeration-values -> I hope this link can help you out sir

Comment: @MauricePheyton: the link you offered is for Java, this question is C#

Comment: If you use the generic version of `GetValues`, it returns a `TEnum` array `public static TEnum[]? GetValues<TEnum> () where TEnum : struct;` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0

Comment: This should really be re-opened. My comment is correct. The duplicate describes the pre-generic solution

Comment: @Flydog57: _"The duplicate describes the pre-generic solution"_ -- which still works today, and still makes this question a duplicate of that one. If you feel you can add new information as an additional answer to the duplicate, by all means do so. That doesn't keep this question from being a duplicate, nor does it mean it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem (conceptual or otherwise)

You could use `GetValues` then `Cast`

```
var set = new HashSet<MyColors>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColors)).Cast<MyColors>());

// or

var set = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColors))
   .Cast<MyColors>()
   .ToHashSet();
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enum.GetValues Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0)

> Retrieves an array of the values of the constants in a specified
> enumeration.

[Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

[Enumerable.ToHashSet Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=net-5.0)

> Creates a HashSet from an IEnumerable using the comparer to
> compare keys.